# Jersey: 500 Internal Error While trying to return XML Data using jersey java framework

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, jersey

Hi Someone help I'm trying to find the bug for past 24hrs. I'm newbie to jersey framework so please help me to clear the error.

The error is:
`org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<org.example.model.Helloworld>.`

The files that I'm using are:

**HelloworldResources.java**

```
package org.example.resources;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.example.model.Helloworld;
import org.example.service.HelloworldService;

import java.util.List;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloworldResources {

    HelloworldService helloworldService = new HelloworldService();

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<Helloworld> getMessage(){
        System.out.println(helloworldService.getMessages());
        return helloworldService.getMessages();
    }
}
```

**Helloworld.java**

```
package org.example.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "helloworld")
public class Helloworld {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Helloworld() {
    }

    public Helloworld(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**HelloworldServices.java**

```
package org.example.service;

import org.example.model.Helloworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloworldService {

    public List<Helloworld> getMessages(){
        List<Helloworld> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Helloworld h1 = new Helloworld(1L, "Ar");
        Helloworld h2 = new Helloworld(2L, "Aravind");
        list.add(h1);
        list.add(h2);
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JerseyHelloworld2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JerseyHelloworld2</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>JerseyHelloworld2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.2</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

These are total files that i'm using
Server: **apache tomcat 10.0.6**

Comment: It's been so long since I've used XML. My guess it has to with the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. It's look like there is a [Jakarta namespace version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind). In order to use JAXB, the class needs to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. But if it's the wrong one, it won't not be recognized.

Comment: Hi @PaulSamsotha thanks for your time but I've included the ```@XmlRootElement```. But there is no change.

Comment: Are you talking about the Jakarta one? Right now you're using the javax one.

Comment: Tah I'm using the javax one for xml binding